# Null key mappings in console vim on OS X

Tags: macos, vim, zsh

Running in zsh on Mac OS X's Terminal.app.

The following 2 keybindings *do work* in MacVim, but *not* console vim (7.4)

```
inoremap <c-space> <c-x><c-o>
inoremap <c-@> <c-space>

" (1) Swapping  windows
nmap <silent> <c-s> :wincmd r<CR>

" (2) Close quickfix window
nmap <silent> <c-space> :ccl<CR>
```

Answer (score 1):

In a terminal, <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>@</kbd> and <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> are almost always the same: the control modifier tells the terminal to strip off bits above the low-order 5.

The code for <kbd>@</kbd> is **`0x40`**, and that for <kbd>space</kbd> is **`0x20`**.  The low-order bits would be 0x1f — and those bits are zero in <kbd>@</kbd> and <kbd>space</kbd>.  So both produce an ASCII NUL (**`0`**).